# Monitor Application Usage on Android

Tags: android, service, notifications, foreground

Is there a way, from a service app, to get notified when an application pops up on the foreground?

I'm writing a service that monitors applications usage so I'd like to be notified everytime an application has the foreground (and not just when it's running). I could do a polling of the running processes but that would be too battery expensive. Do you know of any other way to be notified by the OS when something goes in FG?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you mean by

> polling of the running processes

i guess it is something like this:

```
    public String getTopActivity(){

    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(4096); 
    return runningTasks.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();

}
```

? I dont think thats very expensive on the battery. I can't think of another possibility.

Comment: with "polling" I mean that I'm currently using getRunningAppProcesses() to check applications and to start logging the time when a new activity begins, but this is heavy on the battery. Thanx for your suggestion!